# Unpack Tuple within dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

Why isn't this unpacking work for my dictionary?

The dictionary is build as follows:

```
cutDict = {'scene1': [('scene3', 1001, 1125)]}
```

I'm trying to unpack this like:

```
for key, (cut, fIn, fOut) in cutDict.iteritems():   
    print key 
    print cut
    print fIn
    print fOut
```

but this results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Right now I'm building the dictionary via:

```
cutDict.setdefault(itm, [])
for cutItm in itm.cut_items_ordered:
    cutInOut = (mostcutItm, recentcutItm.cut_item_in, callcutItm.cut_item_out)
    cutDict[itm].append(cutInOut):
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did just copy the directory out of my terminal. this is how it comes out <Cut Sequence 1>: [(<CutItem New Cut Item 3>, 1001, 1125)]

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unfortunetly im not sure why it adds both [] and () im just built a var that is being populated by other vars 3 in total and the appended to the dict.

Comment: Then you have a list still, containing 1 element, a tuple. Please do put that into your question, and add the full traceback of the exception you get. You don't need the `self.` reference here, it'll make for an easier to reproduce [mcve] if you dropped that. The `<Cut Sequence>` objects are also a bit of a distraction.

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix the nesting issue because you don't share how you build the dictionary. That'd be a separate question too.

Comment: Thank you for the editing @MartijnPieters.

Comment: From your edit it is clear you can potentially have 0 or more than 1 `cutInOut` structure in your list, at which point your unpacking operation is not feasible anymore. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your value is not a tuple, it is a list with **one element**, which is a tuple; the nested tuple has 3 elements. Because the *outer* container has only one element, your unpacking assignment fails.

The following does work, by adding another layer, *provided there is always exactly one element*:

```
for key, ((cut, fIn, fOUT),) in cutDict.iteritems():
```

or you can use list syntax:

```
for key, [(cut, fIn, fOUT)] in cutDict.iteritems():
```

Demo:

```
>>> cutDict = {'scene1': [('scene3', 1001, 1125)]}
>>> for key, ((cut, fIn, fOUT),) in cutDict.iteritems():
...     print key, cut, fIn, fOut
...
scene1 scene3 1001 1125
>>> for key, [(cut, fIn, fOUT)] in cutDict.iteritems():
...     print key, cut, fIn, fOut
...
scene1 scene3 1001 1125
```

Alternatively, remove the nesting, the outer list is redundant.

If your dictionary really can have **more than one** item in it, then the outer list is of course not redundant, but then you can't use iterable unpacking *either*. You'd have to add another loop instead:

```
for key, cuts in cutDict.iteritems():
    for cut, fIn, fOUT in cuts:
        # ...
```

Comment: @PetterÖstergren: yes, thereby removing the problem altogether.

Comment: Martijn, can you say a word on why you would be using `iteritems()` here, rather than just `for key in cutDict`? I guess the whole _for X, Y_ loop would not be as concise when doing `for key in cutDict`, as I would have to pull in `cutDict[key]` as well? Is that it? Thanks!

Comment: @patrick: that's exactly it. Why only loop over the keys when you are also always going to use the values?

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't realize Python unpacking was smart enough to nest unpacks in this way. I never fail to learn something from Martijn's answers, no matter how long I work in the language.